# Use part of type to create another one

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have this type called `TranslationsData`:

```
[key: string]: { translation: { state: AnotherType } };
```

I want to use this part:

```
[key: string]: { translation: { state:
```

in another type, so the only type that changes is the `AnotherType` part.

Is there a way to do it? Kind of higher order type.

I know there is smth like this Type, but I have no idea what it's called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest option in this case would be to make the initial type generic, something like the following.

```js
type Foo<T> = {
  [key: string]: { translation: { state: T } }
}

type TranslationsData = Foo<AnotherType>
type SomethingElse = Foo<Bar>
```